# Python query for code examples

Tags: python, quotations

I want to create something like a dictionary for python code examples. My problem is, that I have to escape all the code examples. Also `r'some string'` is not useful. Would you recommend to use an other solution to query this entries?

```
import easygui

lex = {"dict": "woerter = {\"house\" : \"Haus\"}\nwoerter[\"house\"]",\
   "for": "for x in range(0, 3):\n    print \"We are on time %d\" % (x)",\
   "while": "while expression:\n    statement(s)"}

input_ = easygui.enterbox("Python-lex","")
output = lex[input_]
b = easygui.textbox("","",output)
```

Comment: Hi Martijn, I edited the post.

Comment: You might just want to read these in from a file of your own format, rather than try and fit the data into python syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use triple quoting:

```
    lex = {"dict": '''\
woerter = {"house" : "Haus"}
woerter["house"]
''',
           "for": '''\
for x in range(0, 3):
    print "We are on time %d" % (x)
''',
           "while": '''\
while expression:
    statement(s)
'''}
```

Triple-quoted strings (using `'''` or `"""` delimiters) preserve newlines and any embedded *single* quotes do not need to be escaped.

The `\` escape after the opening `'''` triple quote escapes the newline at the start, making the value a little easier to read. The alternative would be to put the first line directly after the opening quotes.

You can make these raw as well; `r'''\n'''` would contain the literal characters `\` and `n`, but literal newlines still remain literal newlines. Triple-quoting works with double-quote characters too: `"""This is a triple-quoted string too"""`. The only thing you'd have to escape is another triple quote in the same style; you only need to escape one quote character in that case:

```
triple_quote_with_embedded_triple = '''Triple quotes use \''' and """ delimiters'''
```

Comment: Thank you! Great, now I am ready to get your 10 MB lex-data. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use json.dumps(data, incident=1) to convert the data, and transfer into easygui.textbox.
like this below:

```
import json
import easygui
resp = dict(...)
easygui.textbox(text=json.dumps(resp, indent=1))
```